# Why won't update action work for nested form fields in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a job model that belongs_to a profile model.  A profile has_many jobs.  I have a nested model form that in which a user adds jobs.  The form is successfully adding jobs, but editing/updating is not working.  Instead, when I try to edit a job, it keeps the old version of the job, but adds the new version as well.  It does not replace the old version with the new one.  How do I fix this?  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the edit/update controllers.

Edit controller:

```
def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

Update controller:

```
def update
    #if current_user.profile.jobs.any?

    @profile = current_user.profile.update_attributes(profile_params)

    if current_user.profile.invalid?
        @profile = current_user.profile
        render :edit, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    else
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
    end
end
```

The thing is, the update controller is working for the non-nested information, it is just not working for the nested jobs.  Here are the strong parameters:

```
def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:title,
           :category, :description, :state, :zip_code, :rate, 
           jobs_attributes: [:firm, :position, :category, :description,
           :begin, :end, :_destroy])        
end
```

And here is the profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :jobs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs , :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Also, here's my routes if that will help:

```
resources :profiles do
   resources :jobs
end
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT

Here are the params from the create action:

```
{"jobs_attributes"=>{"1383593195849"=>{"firm"=>"1st firm", "position"=>"1st position",
 "category"=>"1st category", "description"=>"1st description", "begin"=>"1999",
 "end"=>"1999", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}
```

And here are the params for the same job when updated:

```
{"jobs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"firm"=>"1st firm", "position"=>"1st position",
 "category"=>"1st category", "description"=>"1st description", "begin"=>"1999",
 "end"=>"1999", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"firm"=>"1st firm", 
 "position"=>"1st position", "category"=>"1st category", 
 "description"=>"1st description", "begin"=>"1999", "end"=>"1999", "_destroy"=>"1"}}}
```

EDIT:

Here are my views.  I don't think they are part of the problem though.

```
= simple_form_for @profile do |f|

  %h3 Jobs
  #jobs
    = f.simple_fields_for :jobs do |job|
      = render 'job_fields', :f => job
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add job', f, :jobs
  = f.submit
```

And here is the "job_fields" partial:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :firm
  = f.input :position
  = f.input :category
  = f.input :begin
  = f.input :end
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Delete box'
  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

Comment: Post params which come to update action

Comment: There are two jobs in the params for update. Is this what it's meant to be? Can you post your views?

Comment: link665, no its not supposed to be like that.  That's the problem, instead f updating the object, it is creating a new instance. I will post the views now.

Comment: What is the `simple_fields_for` method?

Comment: @link664 That's from the Simple Forms gem. Google would do you well.

Comment: Any ideas?  I can't figure this out for the life of me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is adding the ':id' symbol to the strong params.  Although I still haven't figured out why and I'm not sure if its secure.

Comment: Had the same problem with nested attributes with the nested form gem. For updating and deleting you indeed have to add the :id and optionally :_destroy https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#strong-parameters

Comment: Yes it is secure and this is the only way nested_attributes will work. The update action of the parent controller needs to know the ids of the nested children otherwise it cannot find them to update them. If you do not supply the id's (or do not whitelist them in controller permit method) then the update will create new objects, as you have seen.